# How do I meet fractional amounts of Refined Metal for trades?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I saw a trade for an item but it was listed as costing 1.27 refined metal. I don't know how to trade with him because I cant find a conversion rate for the fractional amount.

Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 2):

Since it takes 2 weapons to make 1 scrap, a weapon is often used in place of half a scrap. 1.27 refined would therefore be 11 scrap (1 scrap is 0.111 refined) plus one weapon (0.5 scrap).

In short: 11 scrap and 1 weapon